# Jenkins / Maven Release Plugin (cascade release)

Tags: maven, jenkins, maven-3, maven-release-plugin, artifactory

I've got a bunch of projects with enough dependencies that the thought of clicking 'Perform Maven Release' and typing in my SVN username/password on each dependent manually, bottom up, brings on a dense fog of procrastination.

So ideally I would just go to my top level project in Jenkins, click a button that does "mvn release:prepare" and voila, all the dependencies and the project itself are released.

My set-up is Maven3, SVN, Jenkins, Artifactory...

Is there a way to run "mvn release:prepare" from Jenkins, which goes and releases the dependents?  Is there a plug-in for this?

If I try to run this command locally, I have a bug: It is happy to release all the dependencies, but then when it comes to releasing the main project, it looks in Artifactory for the released dependency jars.  But of course they are not there - they are in my local repo, but not in artifactory's repo.  I would prefer to do it on the build server, since it won't have any idiosyncrasies of my environment.

But if there is not a jenkins plug-in for this, how might I do the release locally, and still have Artifactory/Jenkins take note of the latest version?

Answer (score 0):

[I updated the answer to provide a better approach]

You have got the [M2Release plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/M2+Release+Plugin) AND the [maven-versions plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/). I don't think that you could do what you want easily. So I would write a script which would act like this :

- Release C (mvn release)
- Update C version in A & B (mvn versions:use-next-releases)
- Release B (mvn release)
- Update B version in A (mvn versions:use-next-releases)
- Release A (mvn release)

Comment: Yep, I've got the latest version of that plugin, but it doesn't do cascading releases.  If you have A depends on B depends on C, you must click 'Perform Maven Release' on C, then on B, then on A.  If you try on A first, it says "Can't release project due to non released dependencies"